# How to colour first six and lastsix rows in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose I have data.table with 18 rows:

```
df <-datasets::mtcars[1:18,]

                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
```

I want to colour first six rows in green colour, and last 6 rows I want to colour in red colour.

How can I do this in shiny app?

Comment: Use a DT table to display it and color the table.

Comment: @MikeWise how can I do this?
Can you provide demo example?

Comment: @MikeWise and the most important thing, that I want to colour data frame not by mouse, but it should be done automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need the `DT` package to display the table and add a
`rowCallback` to finalize the row styling:

```
library(DT)

df <- datasets::mtcars[1:18,]

DT::datatable(df, 
              options = list(
                  pageLength = 25,
                  rowCallback = JS('function(row, data, index, rowId) {',
                                   'console.log(rowId)',
                                   'if(rowId < 6) {',
                                   'row.style.backgroundColor = "red";',
                                   '}',
                                   'if(rowId >= ', nrow(df) - 6,') {',
                                   'row.style.backgroundColor = "green";',
                                   '}',
                                   '}')
              )
)
```

To use in a Shiny app use `DT::renderDataTable()` in `server` and `DT::dataTableOutput()` in `ui`

[image]

Comment: Nice colors -  :)

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you:)

Comment: If it's possible can you explain your syntax: how do you identify, that exactly first 6 rows should be coloured by green and last 6 by red?

Comment: It mostly is `JS` rather than `R`. `if(rowId < 6)` set background = "red", `if(rowId >= ', nrow(df) - 6,')` set background = "green".  Btw, there was an error that was selecting first and last _3_ rows, but the picture shows 6, I corrected the code